# Applying lambda to pandas dataframe based on conditiional in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe like so

```
product        complaint
Student Loan   words words words
Mortgage       words words words
Credit Card    words words words
Student Loan   words words words
```

I am trying to pre-process the words within each complaint cell but I would like to do so based on the product. This line of code applies my pre-processing function to every cell in the column 'complaint' and it works fine

```
df['complaint'] =df['complaint'].apply(lambda x: pre_process(x))
```

My pre-processing function basically tokenises the text, removes stopwords and lemmatises the complaint.

I want to take this one step further by removing a customised stopword list based on the product. So Mortgage, Student Loan and credit Card all have a different list of stopwords that I want to apply to only those relevant complaints. Something along these lines if it would work:

```
df['complaint'] =df['complaint'].apply(lambda x: pre_process(x,Student_stopwords) if df['product'] == "Student Loan')
df['complaint'] =df['complaint'].apply(lambda x: pre_process(x,mortgage_stopwords) if df['product'] == "Mortgage")
df['complaint'] =df['complaint'].apply(lambda x: pre_process(x,creditcard_stopwords) if df['product'] == "Credit Card")
```

I know this is probably horribly inefficient but thats how i would imagine it being except I have no idea how to just apply my pre-processing function only to particular cells.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a separate function and then use apply. Something like this:

```
def which_preproc(row):
    return student if row['product'] == 'student' 
    # similarly for others and other preprocessing you want
```

and then use apply:

```
df['complaint'] = df.apply(which_preproc, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
def pre_process_wrapper(x):
    complaint = x['complaint']
    if complaint=="Mortgage":
        complaint = pre_process(complaint, Student_stopwords)
    elif:
        ...

    return complaint
df['complaint'] =df.apply(pre_process, axis=1)
```

I have written an extra wrapper function that calls your `pre_process` function and returns the pre_processed `complaint`. You can basically use that to an `apply` function at the dataframe level.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
df['complaint'] = df.apply(lambda row: pre_process(row[1],row[0]), axis=1)['complaint']
```

Comment: How exactly does this code filter my dataframe based on the product? There's no mention of my products here at all.